# Spectral sequences coming from filtrations (Postnikov systems) in triangulated categories: references and convergence

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, spectral-sequences, triangulated-categories

Let $c^i: M^{\ge i+1}\to M^{\ge i}$ for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$ be an sequence of morphisms in a triangulated category $C$ and assume that $M^{\ge i}$ are equipped with compatible morphisms into an object $M$ of $C$. I would like to relate the (co)homology of $M$ with that of $M^{\ge i}$ and also of $M^i=Cone(c^i)[i]$. So, for $H:C\to A$ being a homological functor ($A$ is an abelian category) I take an exact couple with $D_1^{pq}=H(M^{\ge p}[p+q])$, $E_1^{pq}=H(M^p[q])$, and connecting morphisms coming from (triangles corresponding to) $c^i$.I have two questions related to this couple and the corresponding spectral sequence.

1. What is the best reference for the following fact: if $M^{\ge i}=0$ for $i$ large enough and $=M$ for $i$ small enough then this spectral sequence converges to $H(M[p+q])$? I only know the exercises after §IV.2 of Gelfand and Manin's "Methods of homological algebra" (where Postnikov systems are treated; the notation there is different and possibly there are some indexing mistakes).
2. If there are no extra restrictions on $M^{\ge i}$ then the spectral in question does not necessarily converge to anything. However, the morphisms $M^{\ge i}\to M$ certainly give certain filtration on $H_{\ast}(M)$; more generally, for any $j\ge 1$ and $D_j^{pq}$ being the corresponding term of the $j-1$th derived couple there is a canonical morphism $D_j^{pq}\to H(M[p+q])$. Does there exist any formalism for treating this situation (some "very weak convergence" of spectral sequences notion)?

An example: if $C$ is the homotopy category of complexes $K(B)$ ($B$ is an additive category) then one can take $M^{\ge i}$ to be the corresponding stupid truncation of a complex $M$ (so, we put zeroes in degrees less than $i$); then $M^i$ is the $i$th term of $M$. If $M$ is a bounded complex then the additional conditions of my first question are fulfilled.

Comment: Are you familiar with Boardman's [Conditionally convergent spectral sequences](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Boardman/ccspseq.pdf)? I think it should at least contain an answer to your first question.

Comment: Sorry: whcih part of this text can be helpful? It appears not to mention "general" triangulated and abelian categories. It probably says something on my second question; yet I wonder whether its ideas were developed further somewhere (in particular, does any well-known terminology related to these convergence question exist now?).

Comment: See Verdier's thesis for a nice general treatment of sseqs in a triangulated category. If you want something easily accessible online, Lurie's treatment in Higher Algebra is nice (as long as infinity categories don't upset you). Both of these sources easily cover (1). For (2), they both go easy on convergence, but it's at least a little more general. Weibel might be another reference. As for Board

Comment: **as for Boardman, while he writes everything in terms of spaces or spectra, everything carries over essentially verbatim to whatever setting you want...

Comment: Oh and of course there's also Cartan-Eilenberg! They have some lingo for convergence. And Boardman defines a bunch of different types of convergence, including conditional convergence, which is the subject of the paper...